# createNamedPipe in python

Tags: python, windows

hello I have two python files(namedpipe)

**a.py**

```
import win32pipe, win32file

p = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(r'\\.\pipe\test_pipe',
    win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
    win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
    1, 65536, 65536,300,None)

win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(p, None)


data = "Hello Pipe"  
win32file.WriteFile(p, data)
```

this pipe creates a namedpipe "test_pipe" and writes the data into the pipe.

**b.py**

```
import win32pipe, win32file
import win32file
fileHandle = win32file.CreateFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\test_pipe",
                              win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                              0, None,
                              win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                              0, None)
data = win32file.ReadFile(fileHandle, 4096)
print data
```

i am able to get the data without any problem. but the data i get is in this form(i have enclosed the output in double quotes)

```
"<0, Hello Pipe>"
```

I am unable to figure out why  all these variables are being printed(<,0 ,>) where is the problem in a.py or b.py and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just what `win32file.ReadFile()` returns. It returns a tuple of the result and the read data. You should verify the result is 0 (or anything else applicable) and then read the data.

```
data = win32file.ReadFile(fileHandle, 4096)
if data[0] == 0:
  print data[1]
else:
  print 'ERROR', data[0]
```

Comment: Additionally, one can print the error message by calling [`win32api.FormatMessage(data[0])`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__FormatMessage_meth.html) or, better yet, raise an `IOError` constructed with the error string.