# how to use already loaded pickle object from another file

Tags: python, pickle, naivebayes

I have created a naive bayes classifier and has used pickle to store it.
Now everytime i excute my script, pickle is loaded taking almost 10-14 seconds.
Is there any way so that i can keep my pickle object loaded into the ram and can access it from another script?

```
def load_classifier(self):
    f=open("segment_to_topic.pickle","rb")
    classifier=pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return classifier
```

Comment: If you load your script many times in a small fraction of time, maybe you should just run a for loop instead of just re-executing.

Comment: I am using it from another file and everytime parameters are different ,therefore can,t use it

Comment: I'm almost sure you can refactor your code to make it take advantage of the pre-loaded model. Otherwise, I don't think you can control RAM banks through python (I may be wrong).

Comment: Please show how you are currently using `load_classifier()` and give more info about this "other file" and how the "other file" is used/called/run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named pipe. UNIX has `os.mkfifo`, and the windows alternative is probably `win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe`.

A UNIX solution would be like this:

**a.py**

```
import os
import pickle
obj = {1:2, 3:4} # any object
fname = "segment_to_topic.pickle"
os.mkfifo(fname)
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(obj, f)
```

**b.py**

```
import pickle
while True:
    try:
        with open('segment_to_topic.pickle','r') as f:
            print pickle.load(f)
    except:
        pass
```

Then you run:

```
python ./b.py &
python ./a.py
```

And `b.py` prints the result:

```
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

If you are on Windows, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319679/createnamedpipe-in-python) may be helpful.

If the scripts are both in python, another solution is to run the second script as a new thread (or process) from the first one. Threads can share their memory in a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) object.